# Call Java class from AS400 Cobol ILE

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, cobol

i wonder if somebody have a sample of simple call a java class (stored into AS400 IFS folder) from AS400 Cobol ILE please.

I found only an RPG sources around the net... I need Cobol sources sample.

Thanks in advance 
Denis

Answer (score 1):

The ILE COBOL Programmer's Guide has an example of calling Java methods. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzase/javcbl.htm

But it's not particularly simple. COBOL doesn't have as much support for calling Java methods as RPG does.

I would write RPG wrapper procedures to call the Java methods, and call the RPG procedures from COBOL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer 
I will try the sample of your link. 
I don't know RPG... so I must make it in Cobol. 

Thanks again 
Denis